# Use 4-digit years for localised dates in a Twig template

Tags: date, symfony, twig, locale

I use the Twig Intl Extension in my Symfony 2.4 project to localize dates:

`{{ post.published_at|localizeddate('short', 'none', locale) }}`

This works well, but does not display the full year in the `yyyy` format and uses the `yy` format instead.

This way, December 31, 2013 would be displayed like 31/12/2013 or 12/31/2013 depending on the locale, instead of 31/12/13 or 31/12/13.

Is there a way to use a 4 digit year with the localised date?

Comment: On my machine configuration I have four digits, but in an other configurations I only have 2 digits. Y don't know what is the difference between them. But I think there is a way to do it without a Twig extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to do it!

I extended the default Twig Intl Extension this way:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig;

class AcmeIntlExtension extends \Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('localizeddate', array($this, 'twigLocalizedDateFilter'), array('needs_environment' => true)),
        );
    }

    public function twigLocalizedDateFilter($env, $date, $dateFormat = 'medium', $timeFormat = 'medium', $locale = null, $timezone = null, $format = null)
    {
        $date = twig_date_converter($env, $date, $timezone);

        $formatValues = array(
            'none'   => \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
            'short'  => \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
            'medium' => \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
            'long'   => \IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
            'full'   => \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        );

        $formatter = \IntlDateFormatter::create(
            $locale,
            $formatValues[$dateFormat],
            $formatValues[$timeFormat],
            $date->getTimezone()->getName(),
            \IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
            $format
        );

        if ($format === null) {
            // Replace yy to y (but yyy should be kept yyy, and yyyy kept as yyyy)
            // This way, years are NEVER shown as "yy" (eg. 14), but always like "yyyy" (eg. 2014)
            $pattern = preg_replace(':(^|[^y])y{2,2}([^y]|$):', '$1y$2', $formatter->getPattern());

            $formatter->setPattern($pattern);
        }

        return $formatter->format($date->getTimestamp());
    }
}
```

It is declared in my Symfony's `app/config.yml` file:

```
services:
    acme.twig.extension.intl:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeIntlExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

I change the default pattern to replace "yy" to "y" (which is the format for 4-digit years, as described here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

This way, it works for all formats and for all locales.

Comment: I've made a change so you can use the old and new way, just add _year to it:

Answer (score 0):

A change on the answer of Michaël Perrin to be able to use the old and new way by adding _year to the date format.

Create the file app/src/Myproject/MyBundle/Twig/Extension/IntlExtension.php with:

```
<?php
namespace Myproject\MyBundle\Twig\Extension;

/**
 * Extension of Twig Intl Extension to add support fo showing 4-digit year. Add
 * '_year' to the date format for it to work, i.e. short_year instead of short.
 */
class IntlExtension extends \Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
{

    /**
     * A new filter must be added for this extension to work. Since this extension
     * extends an existing one, the filter should be loaded after the original one.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFilters()
    {
        $filters = [];

        // Add all filters but the localizeddate created by the parent.
        foreach (parent::getFilters() as $filter) {
            if ('localizeddate' !== $filter->getName()) {
                $filters[] = $filter;
            }
        }

        // Add custom version of 'localizeddate' which adds support showing 4-digit years.
        $filters[] = new \Twig_SimpleFilter('localizeddate', array($this, 'twigLocalizedDateFilter'), array('needs_environment' => true));

        return $filters;
    }

    /**
     * If the date format has _year in it, the format returned by Intl, will be
     * changed to show a 4-digit year.
     *
     * @param \Twig_Environment $env
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @param string $dateFormat
     * @param string $timeFormat
     * @param string $locale
     * @param string $timezone
     * @param string $format
     * @return string
     */
    public function twigLocalizedDateFilter(\Twig_Environment $env, $date, $dateFormat = 'medium', $timeFormat = 'medium', $locale = null, $timezone = null, $format = null, $calendar = 'gregorian')
    {
        $date = twig_date_converter($env, $date, $timezone);

        $formatValues = array(
            'none' => \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
            'short' => \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
            'medium' => \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
            'long' => \IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
            'full' => \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        );

        $formatter = \IntlDateFormatter::create(
            $locale,
            $formatValues[$this->getDateFormat($dateFormat)],
            $formatValues[$timeFormat],
            PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50500 ? $date->getTimezone() : $date->getTimezone()->getName(),
            'gregorian' === $calendar ? \IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN : \IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
            $format
        );

        if ($format === null && $this->showFullYear($dateFormat)) {
            // Replace yy to y (but yyy should be kept yyy, and yyyy kept as yyyy)
            // This way, years are NEVER shown as "yy" (eg. 14), but always like "yyyy" (eg. 2014)
            $pattern = preg_replace(':(^|[^y])y{2,2}([^y]|$):', '$1y$2', $formatter->getPattern());

            $formatter->setPattern($pattern);
        }

        return $formatter->format($date->getTimestamp());
    }

    /**
     * If the given date format has _year in it, true is returned, otherwise false.
     *
     * @param string $dateFormat
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function showFullYear($dateFormat)
    {
        return (strpos($dateFormat, '_year') !== false);
    }

    /**
     * The date format will be returned without the part '_year' if it contains it.
     * @param string $dateFormat
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getDateFormat($dateFormat)
    {
        return str_replace('_year', '', $dateFormat);
    }
}
```

And, off course the addition in app/config/config.yml

```
services:
    myproject.twig.extension.intl:
        class: Myproject\MyBundle\Twig\Extension\IntlExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution to extend intl extension is good, but you can do it more easily. If you give a deep look in the documentation, you'll see the extension has a `format` argument. So you can do:

`{{ post.published_at|localizeddate('short', 'none', locale, null, 'd/m/y HH:mm') }}`

The format follow ICU format guide. For 4 digit years you can use `y`or `yyyy`. Full documentation: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
{{ post.published_at|localizeddate('d/m/Y', 'none', locale) }}
```

You can use your own format for this with special pkaceholders, for example `Y` mean **YYYY** date format, check documentation about [localizeddate](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/intl.html) filter.

Comment: The problem is that it will not use the locale any more. Dates will always be displayed like 31/12/2013 and not 12/31/2013 for the en_US locale for instance...

Comment: I understand, and I think you need to realize localization manually for your case

Comment: I think you're right... that's really too bad though! Thanks for your help anyway.